# Parent category products set as anchor do not show on front-end - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, product, category, magento2.3

We are facing a very strange problem and hope someone has maybe an idea to help.

We are using Magento version 2.3.1

No products of the main category, set as anchor are showing up in the front-end. Thing is, we have this parent category here ID:4) set as Anchor. Total quantity of products of child categories here is 485.

This here is the setting: https://pasteboard.co/Iurzba6.jpg

It seems somehow, that 485 products in this category are somewhat not displaying, but 125 products when using the filter do.

We have re-indexed multiple times, deployed, cleaned the cache and all, but products are not showing.

Only when we say "Anchor = No" and manually add products it is working (but also only up to a certain quantity). Strangely it is also working once we use the filter and product quantity is below 200. Then all works fine.

But for now, only the static block with content is showing in the front end, but no products.

We have disabled all filter modules, but same thing happens. All other categories work just fine and products do show up!

Has anyone maybe experience the same behaviour and has a hint or an idea, where to look at to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance and best regards.